# How to set an array of nested objects that has variable size as source for javafx TableView TableColumns

Tags: java, javafx

I have an object of type ClassTestEvaluation. It holds an ArrayList of type Task. This array can have any number of tasks and is not predictable. I want to set up a table view that will show the given tasks in columns so that the user can enter points.

My problem is that I have no idea how to set an array of variable length that is part of another object as source for my table view. I cannot build a wrapper like ClassTestEvaluationItem with simple members task1, task2, etc. since the number of tasks is not fixed. Thus my question is what do I have to do to properly set the propertyValueFactories for the tasks columns?

I have followed lots of tutorials like the one here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm. It's generally speaking no problem to follow and get them working. But they only deal with simple (flat) data.

```
TableView<ClassTestEvaluation> table = new TableView<>();
TableColumn colFirstName = new TableColumn("Vorname");
colFirstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClassTestEvaluation, String>("firstName");
TableColumn colLastName = new TableColumn("Nachname");
colLastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClassTestEvaluation, String>("lastName");

table.getColumns().addAll(colFirstName, colLastName);

ArrayList<Task> tasks = classTestEvaluation.getTasks();
for(Task t : tasks) {
    TableColumn colTask = new TableColumn(t.getTitle());
    table.getColumns().add(colTask);
}
```

As you can see it's not hard to set PropertyValueFactory for colFirstName and colLastName. But how do I do that for the tasks that are variable in 
length and are stored in an array which itself is part of the 
ClassTestEvaluation object?

Depending on the number of tasks a classtest has got, I want my table view to look like that:

Firstname | Lastname | Task 1 | Task 2 | ...

I hope someone can help me out here since I don't get it. Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1:**

To make my data source a bit more clear, here is the relevant structure of my ClassTestEvaluation and Task classes:

```
public class ClassTestEvaluation{
    // ... more members ...
    ArrayList<Task> tasks = ArrayList<>();


    public ArrayList<Task> getTasks(){
        return this.tasks;
    }

    // ...more methods...

}



public class Task{
    private int id;
    private int idClassTestEvaluation;
    private Double points;
    private String title;

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public Double getPoints(){    // This methods needs to be connected as data source for tasks cells.
        return this.points;
    }

    // ...more methods...
}
```

The data comes from an sqlite database, where every task is connected via foreign key to a specific ClassTestEvaluation. When necessary a specific ClassTestEvaluation is constructed and gets populated with the corresponding tasks. Thus I need to find a way to make the tasks (i.e. not only their titles as columns, but also their points as cells) available and editable inside the table view.

Comment: If `Evaluation(1)` has 5 `Tasks` and `Evaluation(2)` has 3, you'd have two unnecessary "Task" columns in the row for #2. Is that desired?

Comment: The number of tasks is the same for all rows at a given time. But it can alter depending on the evaluation chosen from a seperate list view. I just don't know how to programmatically connect the values inside the array that is stored in the evaluation object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually found the solution to my own question and thought this might be of interest to others. To recall: my problem was that I didn't know how to built columns out of an array of variable length, which is part of another item (composed).

What I needed to understand is how cellValueFactory, cellFactory and onEditCommit can be used togehter with callbacks or lambdas respectivly to get the desired result. This took me quite a while.

Here is what I did to get it:

```
    private void createTableColumnsForTasks(ClassTestEvaluation cte) {
    int resultCounter = 1;

    // For each given task in ClassTestEvaluation...
    for (Task t : cte.getTasks()) {

        // ...create a column for the corresponding points reached (0 in the beginning).
        TableColumn<ClassTestEvaluationRow, Double> colResult = new TableColumn<>("A" + resultCounter + " (" + t.getPoints() + ")");
        resultCounter++;

        // Make the column editable.
        colResult.setEditable(true);


        // Define how the values in the task columns will be set.
        colResult.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ClassTestEvaluationRow, Double> row) -> {

            ClassTestEvaluationRow cter = row.getValue();

            for(Result r : cter.getResults()) {
                if(r.getIdTask() == t.getId()) {
                    ObservableValue<Double> obsResult = new SimpleObjectProperty<Double>(r.getPoints());
                    return obsResult;               
                }
            }

            return null;

        });



        // Create combo box to choose points from for each given task and result.
        createTableColumnComboBoxForResultEditing(colResult, t);


        // Create method to store edited data in selected ClassTestEvaluationRow.
        createOnEditCommitMethods(colResult, t);

        ((EvaluatorUI) this.getView()).getTableView().getColumns().add(colResult);

    }

}



private void createTableColumnComboBoxForResultEditing(TableColumn<ClassTestEvaluationRow, Double> colResult, Task t) {
    ArrayList<Double> cbPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    for(double i = 0.0; i <= t.getPoints(); i = i+0.5) {
        cbPoints.add(i);
    }

    ObservableList<Double> obsPoints = FXCollections.observableArrayList(cbPoints);

    colResult.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.<ClassTestEvaluationRow, Double>forTableColumn(obsPoints));      
}




private void createOnEditCommitMethods(TableColumn<ClassTestEvaluationRow, Double> colResult, Task t) {

    colResult.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<ClassTestEvaluationRow, Double> event) -> {
        TablePosition<ClassTestEvaluationRow, Double> pos = event.getTablePosition();
        Double newValue = event.getNewValue();
        int row = pos.getRow();
        ClassTestEvaluationRow cter = (ClassTestEvaluationRow) event.getTableView().getItems().get(row);

        for(Result result : cter.getResults()) {
            if(result.getIdTask() == t.getId()){
                result.setPoints(newValue);
                classTestEvaluationsService.updateResult(cter.getClassTestEvaluation(), result);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

I hope this is of help to some of you. Greetings.